# In an Imagej plugin, how to make a ROI available or active as a Selection

Tags: java, imagej

I have written a java plugin for ImageJ that does create a polygon then does a setRoi() call then an updateandDraw() call, all that to make the ROI polygon available to many ImageJ menu commands like BLUR etc for further action.......the plugin works well and does create the polygon in a window, but the ROI created does not seem to be active as no ImageJ standard menu command can operate on it, in other words its is not yet a "Selection" on which any menu commands can act upon. I dont know if it is a matter of making the ROI "active" or if a "Selection" is fundamentally different from a "ROI" or if this can only be accomplished in a script or macro etc.....Thanks for your help and regards.

Answer (score 2):

In ImageJ 1.x, [selection](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-10.html#toc-Section-10) and ROI are equivalent terms. After running the following Java plugin:

```
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.gui.PolygonRoi;
import ij.gui.Roi;
import ij.plugin.PlugIn;

public class My_Plugin implements PlugIn {

    public void run(String arg) {
        ImagePlus imp = IJ.getImage();
        int[] xpoints = {10,100,100,10};
        int[] ypoints = {10,100,10,100};
        imp.setRoi(new PolygonRoi(xpoints,ypoints,4,Roi.POLYGON));
    }

}
```

a command like *Process > Filters > Gaussian Blur...* works as expected, i.e. only the region within the selected polygon will be blurred.